# Xamarin.Forms: NavigationController is null in PageRenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I am trying to use `PageRenderer` to customize/reposition elements of `ToolbarItem` for iOS but here `NavigationController` throwing null reference exception.
Below my code

```
   public class MyNavigationRenderer: PageRenderer
    {    
        public new MyNavigationBar Element
        {
            get { return (MyNavigationBar)base.Element; }
        }
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
            var LeftNavList = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();
            var rightNavList = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();
            var navigationItem = this.NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem;

            for (var i = 0; i < Element.ToolbarItems.Count; i++)
            {
                var reorder = (Element.ToolbarItems.Count - 1);
                var ItemPriority = Element.ToolbarItems[reorder - i].Priority;

                if (ItemPriority == 1)
                {
                   UIBarButtonItem LeftNavItems = navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems[i];
                   LeftNavList.Add(LeftNavItems);
                }
                else if (ItemPriority == 0)
                {
                   UIBarButtonItem RightNavItems = navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems[i];
                   rightNavList.Add(RightNavItems);
                }
            }
             navigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItems(LeftNavList.ToArray(), false);
             navigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(rightNavList.ToArray(), false);
        }
    }
```

Below `MyNavigationBar.cs` class in portable/shared forms project

```
public class MyNavigationBar : NavigationPage
{
    public MyNavigationBar(Page content) : base(content)
    {
        Init();
    }
    private void Init()
    {
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem() { Icon = "kid", Priority = 0, Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary });
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem() { Text = "License", Priority = 0, Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary });
    }    
}
```

App starting

```
public App ()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new MyNavigationBar(new LoginPage());
}
```

See below screenshot getting exception

[image]

Comment: If I am not mistaken the renderer can make a few passes though there. Just check if its null and short circuit

Comment: It seems to be issue only. If i try like below, I am getting null exception at `RightBarButtonItems[i]` below modified code. 
            `var nav=new UINavigationController();
             var navigationItem = nav.NavigationItem;
             navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems[i];`

Comment: I got that code from here 
[This](https://timeyoutake.it/2016/01/02/creating-a-left-toolbaritem-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: I think your `NavigationController` does not have a `TopViewController`. Or can you - standing in the debugger as your screenshots shows - check what's null there?

Comment: Here `NavigationController` is null, I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, but in my case, I was trying to get NavigationController from content page which didn't had NavigationController, make sure you null check before calling TopViewController,

```
 var navController = this.NavigationController;
 if(navController == null)
 {
     return;
 }
 UINavigationItem navigationItem = navController.TopViewController.NavigationItem;
```

For example,
When User opens the app, he will be presented with Login page, which didn't had any Navigation Bar.